# Number of monthly occurrences of bill date between pay dates

Tags: arrays, excel, date, excel-formula

For information; today is 24/01/2018.

I have formulas that put my **previous pay date** in a cell of a worksheet named in the format "YYYYMM". In this case cell **201712!B1**, which is based on the month of the last pay date that has occurred.

The **next pay date** is in **template!b1**.

The **date a bill comes out of my account** is in **[@[start date]]**

The best formulas I've managed to come up with at the moment are the array formulas:

To work out how many times payments have occurred:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(INDIRECT(TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TEMPLATE!$B$1),MONTH(TEMPLATE!$B$1)-1,DAY(TEMPLATE!$B$1)),"yyyymm")&"!$b$1")&":"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())))),"dd")=TEXT([@[START DATE]],"dd")))}
```

The above seems to be functioning okay... but I'm now questioning it, as

To work out how many times payments will still occur I have:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())+1)&":"&TEMPLATE!$B$1-1)),"dd")=TEXT([@[START DATE]],"dd")))}
```

My **last pay date was 22/12/2017** and my **next pay date is 25/01/2018**.

The second formula is showing that I still have one payment left to make for a payment that occurs on the 25th of every month within this pay period of which today should be the last day.

I think I may be overcomplicating this... any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second formula malfunctions because of how `ROW` function works, for example `ROW(3:1)` gives you the same as `ROW(1:3)` so in your formula when today+1 is **after** next payday-1 you still get both those dates, hence counting a payment date that's out of range

Why not just check if bill dates are after today, but before the next payday, like this:

`=COUNTIFS([@[START DATE]],">"&TODAY(),[@[START DATE]],"<"&TEMPLATE!$B$1)`

For bills paid between last payday and today inclusive you can do a similar thing, i.e.

`=COUNTIFS([@[START DATE]],">="&INDIRECT(TEXT(EDATE(TEMPLATE!$B$1,-1),"yyyymm")&"!B1"),[@[START DATE]],"<="&TODAY())`